# Getting error when dynamically unpivoting in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql, unpivot

The goal is to dynamically pivot data and then dynamically unpivot it.

I am getting an error saying `Invalid ControlNo`

I am assuming its because variable `@colsUnpivot` contains ControlNo column.

But how can I fix it? I definitely need that ControlNo.

[image]

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##A
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table1

Create table #Table1 ( ControlNo INT, Bound INT, Declined INT, Rated INT, Quoted INT, QuoteStatus VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO #Table1 (ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus) 
    VALUES  (1111,1,0,1,1,'Lost'), 
            (2222,0,1,0,1,'No Action'), 
            (3333,1,1,0,0,NULL), 
            (4444,1,0,0,1,'Lost'), 
            (5555,0,1,1,1,'No Action')

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @finalquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QuoteStatus) FROM #Table1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
--PRINT @columns

set @finalquery = '
        select  p.controlno,
                p.Bound, 
                p.Declined, 
                p.Rated,
                p.Quoted,' + @columns + '
        into ##A 
        from ( select ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus
                from #Table1
            )a 
    pivot 
    ( 
     COUNT(QuoteStatus) 
     for QuoteStatus IN (' + @columns + ') 
    )p '

exec(@finalquery)

--SELECT * 
--FROM ##a


DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') 
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
--PRINT @colsUnpivot

set @query 
  = 'select ControlNo, Counts, Status
     from ##A
     unpivot
     (
        Counts
        for Status in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: check your collation you are creating a column in all lower case controlno and reading in mixed case

Comment: You have ControlNo in the select list and the unpivot group... `select @colsunpivot`

Comment: Thanks. But I am confused how would I not have it in @colsunpivot  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your sample output was that, a sample, and you excluded the other control numbers. If so, changing the `where` clause in your `stuff` will remove that column from the `unpivot` group, and give you desired results. You can't return a column that you are pivoting or unpivoting.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##A
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #table1

Create table #Table1 ( ControlNo INT, Bound INT, Declined INT, Rated INT, Quoted INT, QuoteStatus VARCHAR(50) )

INSERT INTO #Table1 (ControlNo, Bound, Declined, Rated, Quoted, QuoteStatus) 
    VALUES  (1111,1,0,1,1,'Lost'), 
            (2222,0,1,0,1,'No Action'), 
            (3333,1,1,0,0,NULL), 
            (4444,1,0,0,1,'Lost'), 
            (5555,0,1,1,1,'No Action')

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @finalquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(QuoteStatus) FROM #Table1 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
--PRINT @columns

set @finalquery = '
        select  p.controlno,
                p.Bound, 
                p.Declined, 
                p.Rated,
                p.Quoted,' + @columns + '
        into ##A 
        from ( select *
                from #Table1
            )a 
    pivot 
    ( 
     COUNT(QuoteStatus) 
     for QuoteStatus IN (' + @columns + ') 
    )p '

exec(@finalquery)

--SELECT * 
--FROM ##a


DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
           --notice i remove controlno here...
           WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##A') and c.name <> 'controlno'
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
--PRINT @colsUnpivot


set @query 
  = 'select  Controlno, Counts, Status
     from ##A
     unpivot
     (
        Counts
        for Status in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

To get your exact output, then just add a where clause to the `set @query`.

```
set @query 
  = 'select  Controlno, Counts, Status
     from ##A
     unpivot
     (
        Counts
        for Status in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
     ) u
     where controlno = 1111'
```